# Retrieving value from a textbox in HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have a table which has textboxes in its cells. All these textboxes are created and populated dynamically by using PHP. I have to iterate through the cells and get the values.

By using the following code, I am able to get the innerHTML of the cells.

```
var tblLang = document.getElementById("tbl_Languages");
var tblrows = tblLang.rows;
for(var i=1; i<tblrows.length; i++){
var tblcells = tblrows[i].cells;
alert(tblcells[0].innerHTML);
```

The output for the given code is

```
<input background-color="#FFFFFF" haslayout="-1" id="txtname_ENU" value=" English" type="text">
```

How could I get the value of the inner textbox? Please help me.

Comment: Why can't you use the `id` of the text input?

Comment: Hi Austin, The tables are dynamically created and populated, with more than one column. So, I cannot get the list of textboxes and iterate through it perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to get the actual dom node from the table cell instead of the innerHTML (a string).  This will allow you to call .value on that node and you're all good.  SOmething like:

```
   tblcells[0].firstChild.value
   // or iterate through children
   var childLength = tblcells.childNodes.length
   for(var i=0;i<childLength;i++){
     alert(tblCells.childNodes[i].value);
   }
```

Also note that in your code when you're iterating `for(var i=1; i<tblrows.length; i++){` you're checking the length of your tblrows array every time which is slow.  You should check that length once, as in my code first, then use it in the loop.

Comment: Hey Brad, Thanks a ton. The first one works fine.

Between, are there any websites which serve as a document repository for Javascript??

Comment: mozilla is always good:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript
look at the guide and core reference, also a good, short book is Douglas Crockfords "javascript, the good parts"

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean:

```
var textBoxValue = document.getElementById("txtname_ENU").value;
alert(textBoxValue);
```

Comment: I want to retrieve the value, but I cannot do it by calling using the ID of the textbox.

Comment: ahh. then:
<pre>
  for(var i=0; i<tblrows.length; i++)
    {
     var tblcells = tblrows[i].cells;
      for(var j=0; j<tblcells.length; j++)
      {
       alert(tblcells[j].firstElementChild.value);
      }
    }
</pre>